# Passing custom data to answer url in in-app voice calling from browser in nexmo

Tags: node.js, vonage

I am implementing the nexmo's in-app voice calling feature using client-sdk in node. 
The feature has been implemented but having trouble with passing custom data to the answer or event url. 
I would like to pass some custom data to answer-url so that i would be able to update my database accordingly. 
but The url is pre-defined in the nexmo dashboard. So anyone has any solution to handle this scenario.. 
Any idea plz?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of custom data do you want to pass? Could you provide some code snippets?

Here's what I've done:

When I make the call, I pass my custom data to my answer_url through query parameters on the URL.

```
 nexmo.calls.create({
    to: [{
      type: 'phone',
      number: TO_NUMBER
    }],
    from: {
      type: 'phone',
      number: NEXMO_NUMBER
    },
    answer_url: ["https://YOUR-URL.com/webhooks/inbound?customData="+yourCustomData]
  }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) console.error(error)
    if (response) console.log(response)
  })
```

Then on the endpoint, I can get the custom data from the request query.

```
app.get('/webhooks/inbound', (req, res) => {
  console.log('custom data: ',req.query.customData);
  ...
});
```

Let me know if this is similar to what you want to do.

Thanks.